# ¿Cual es el path a un archivo situado en la carpeta raw en android studio?

Tags: java, android

me gustaría conseguir el path al archivo "datos.txt" situado en la carpeta "raw" en "res", en Windows sería algo parecido a "app/res/raw/data", pero no consigo que funcione.

Ya lo he intentado con el 
`String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.datos;` pero cuando creo un objeto File con el path, su método `exists()` me devuelve false y salta una excepción.

Me gustaría guardar el archivo como un objeto File para pasarlo por RandomAccessFile, así que tampoco puedo `InputStream arquivo = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.datos);`

Gracias de antemano, un saludo

Comment: En realidad lo que se obtiene con: "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.datos; es un Uri, si quieres el path de este Uri obten el Uri y puedes usar uriArchivo.getPath().toString() para obtener la ruta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay un path como tal, en realidad puedes obtener la `Uri` donde es localizado el archivo dentro de tu directorio `/raw`:

```
 Uri archivo = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/myFile");
```

y a partir de este `Uri` obtener el `File`:

```
   File file = new File(archivo.getPath());
    if(file.exists()){
        Log.i("Archivo", "file existe! ");
    }else{
        Log.i("Archivo", "No existe! ");
    }
```

---

También puedes obtener el `InputStream` lo puedes obtener mediante `openRawResource()` :

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myFile);
```

al obtener el `InputStream` puedes usar este método para crear un archivo :

```
private void copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream in, File file) {
    OutputStream out = null;

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=in.read(buf))>0){
            out.write(buf,0,len);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        // Ensure that the InputStreams are closed even if there's an exception.
        try {
            if ( out != null ) {
                out.close();
            }

            in.close();
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

De esta forma puedes crear un archivo a partir del `InputStream`

```
 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myFile);
 String pathFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Android/data/nuevo_archivo.txt";
 copyInputStreamToFile(arq, new File(pathFile));
```

Comment: Perfecto, probé las dos formas y ambas funcionan como necesito. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @Jorgesys

Comment: Un placer ayudarte @Bugzilla saludos!