# Cambiar sonido de alarma del reloj Android Studio

Tags: android

he buscado como asignar un sonido de la carpeta raw al tono de alarma del reloj del telefono (despertador), pero nada me ha funcionado. Me funciona para cambiar el tono Ringtone y Notificación pero Alarma no he podido dar con eso. Aca muestro como funciona para Notificación.

```
Uri path = Uri.parse( "android.resource://" + "com.example.tablas/" + R.raw.xxx);
                                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                            context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, path );
                                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone( context, path );
```

NOTA: Tampoco funciona al cambiar a `TYPE_ALARM`.
Si alguien me podría ayudar se lo agradecería. Gracias.

Comment: Estas obteniendo incorrectamente la Uri del archivo, trata como indico en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta para obtener la Uri del archivo es:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/<nombre archivo>");
```

recuerda que no debes definir la extensión del archivo, únicamente su nombre.

Revisa :

[¿Cual es el path a un archivo situado en la carpeta raw en android studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191708/cual-es-el-path-a-un-archivo-situado-en-la-carpeta-raw-en-android-studio)

Comment: Eso esta bien el tema es que no puedo rescatar el recurso para que quede como sonidos Dafault de Alarma